# Error in running a Web project via Eclipse (deployed to tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying run a Spring MVC based project via eclipse, but each time I try to access the app, getting following error:

WARN PageNotFound:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

The strange part is, if I manually generate the WAR and copy over to the SAME tomcat installation and start the server manually, it works without any problem.

I have tried to "clean", "publish" again, change the tomcat webapps directory in "Servers" configuration, but no luck.

Any suggestion/idea in this regard highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

properties -> deployment assembly -> make sure you have declared all the dependencies here to be included in the deployment war.

If you use maven, choose to include all maven dependencies.

And you need to add all projects you have in your workspace and used by your web project if any.

Comment: I have verified all dependencies are included and dependent projects also listed.

Comment: what does the console produces? any exception, give's some more info

Comment: The console shows the messages for deployment and "server started" etc., but as soon as I hit the application, I get the "No mapping found.." error.

Comment: you need to add some logging framework to see what is going on. Look like you haven't configured one